# Java Producer for AWS MSK

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

As part of my existing application (which runs in the public network), I want to send some messages to `AWS MSK` Kafka cluster. As my Kafka cluster is within a `VPC`, I couldn't connect to it directly. That I understood. In my research, I came across a pattern - by running confluent's kafka-rest on a `ec2-instance` within same `VPC` having a `public subnet`. But my application needs to make `HTTP` calls to send the messages to my kafka cluster, which adds extra latency.

I'm trying to figure out a way by having some `persistent connection` and send messages to `MSK` cluster.

Any Thoughts Please!!

Comment: If you are not able to (securely) open the Kafka TCP port on the VPC, then you're going to need some sort of proxy, whether that is the REST Proxy or something else.

Comment: Even, I tried by running kafka-proxy on a ec2 within same VPC, but when I send a HTTP call to it, failing with `ERROR Uncaught exception in thread 'kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1': 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. This is on xlarge instance.

Comment: The instance size doesn't matter if you don't increase the heap space of the JVM

Comment: After updating heap size from 256M to 1024M, now I'm getting a different error response. `INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=fetchMetadata, deadlineMs=1626200389678, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1626200389813) timed out at 1626200389713 after 1 attempt(s)`

Comment: Seems like a network issue. You can increase the retries or the timeouts

Comment: Updated below properties from 1000 to 10000, but no luck.
`consumer.request.timeout.ms = 10000
simpleconsumer.pool.timeout.ms=10000`

Comment: Those are consumer properties. Your error is from the adminclient, which has separate configs